# Which exception to throw to return HTTP status code in Azure HttpTrigger Function

Tags: azure-functions

In a C# Azure function what Exception classes can be thrown to cause specific HTTP status codes to be returned from the API.  For example a "404 Not Found" when a key lookup in an in-memory structure has no hits.

I would like to avoid returning codes up the stack when we have exceptions available that were created for this purpose.

Comment: you can return `NotFoundObjectResult`, `BadRequestObjectResult` e.t.c. to return specific Http status error code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be two ways to do this, however, one is in preview.

**Preview:**

https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Function-Filters

**Middlware:**

If you run your Azure function as an *isolated process* you can add your own custom middleware which could take care of exception handling.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide#middleware

```
// Source above
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults(workerApplication =>
    {
        // Register our custom middlewares with the worker

        workerApplication.UseMiddleware<ExceptionHandlingMiddleware>();

        workerApplication.UseMiddleware<MyCustomMiddleware>();

        workerApplication.UseWhen<StampHttpHeaderMiddleware>((context) =>
        {
            // We want to use this middleware only for http trigger invocations.
            return context.FunctionDefinition.InputBindings.Values
                          .First(a => a.Type.EndsWith("Trigger")).Type == "httpTrigger";
        });
    })
    .Build();
```

In doing so you would need to then return [HttpResponseData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.functions.worker.http.httpresponsedata?view=azure-dotnet&preserve-view=true) object.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide#differences-with-net-class-library-functions